# Are Two Different Processes Trying to Execute Pipe Instruction segment?

Tags: pipe, fork, xv6

This is how the shell in xv6 handles **PIPE** command (From xv6-source code).

```
8650 case PIPE:
8651     pcmd = (struct pipecmd*)cmd;
8652     if(pipe(p) < 0)
8653         panic("pipe");
8654     if(fork1() == 0){
8655         close(1);
8656         dup(p[1]);
8657         close(p[0]);
8658         close(p[1]);
8659         runcmd(pcmd−>left);
8660     }
8661     if(fork1() == 0){
8662         close(0);
8663         dup(p[0]);
8664         close(p[0]);
8665         close(p[1]);
8666         runcmd(pcmd−>right);
8667     }
8668     close(p[0]);
8669     close(p[1]);
8670     wait();
8671     wait();
8672 break;
```

And from my knowledge of fork, after the fork1() call in line 8661, there will be total 4 processes running. From the beginning, say the mother process is P. After the fork1() of line 8654, there are 2 processes, P and newly created C1. Both of them executes line 8661. So, 2 more new processes are created. C2 from P and C3 from C1.

But, for PIPE to work correctly, only C3 should execute line 8662 - 8666. Will process C2 not execute them? As C2 is a child process, I think it does. If it does, is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`runcmd` never returns, so process C1 never gets to line 8661, C2 never gets to line 8668, and C3 doesn't exist.